# How to open a text file of some xyz format which is placed in the sd card in the android device

Tags: android, file

How to open a text file of some xyz format which is placed in the sd card in the android device, if anybody knows please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File textFile = new File(sdPath, "textfile.xyz")
```

from there use the common Java IO streams.

Check also the examples coming with  the Android SDK.